# Exception when running Scrapy tutorial on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, sqlite, scrapy

I'm trying to learn Scrapy, and I'm running it on Mac OS X 10.11.2.
I'm following the tutorial, I've download the tutorial files and created a new Spider file as described here: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.0/intro/tutorial.html

When I try to run the spider, I get the following exception:

```
2015-12-11 19:04:05 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.3 started (bot: tutorial)
2015-12-11 19:04:05 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11
2015-12-11 19:04:05 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'tutorial.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['tutorial.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'tutorial'}
2015-12-11 19:04:06 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: CloseSpider, TelnetConsole, LogStats, CoreStats, SpiderState
Unhandled error in Deferred:
2015-12-11 19:04:06 [twisted] CRITICAL: Unhandled error in Deferred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 150, in _run_command
cmd.run(args, opts)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/commands/crawl.py", line 57, in run
self.crawler_process.crawl(spname, **opts.spargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 153, in crawl
d = crawler.crawl(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1274, in unwindGenerator
return _inlineCallbacks(None, gen, Deferred())
--- <exception caught here> ---
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1128, in _inlineCallbacks
result = g.send(result)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 71, in crawl
self.engine = self._create_engine()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 83, in _create_engine
return ExecutionEngine(self, lambda _: self.stop())
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 64, in __init__
self.scheduler_cls = load_object(self.settings['SCHEDULER'])
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 44, in load_object
mod = import_module(module)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/scheduler.py", line 6, in <module>
from queuelib import PriorityQueue    
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/queuelib/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from queuelib.queue import FifoDiskQueue, LifoDiskQueue
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/queuelib/queue.py", line 5, in <module>
import sqlite3 
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
from dbapi2 import *
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 28, in <module>
from _sqlite3 import *
 exceptions.ImportError: No module named _sqlite3
2015-12-11 
19:04:06 [twisted] CRITICAL:
```

Initially I tought that I had a problem in my sqlite installation but it seems to be working if I run the command sqlite3 from the command line. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this iss a known homebrew problem, see [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/22655)

I think you should reinstall homebrew's sqlite and python